# What does the comma operator mean?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, operator-precedence, comma-operator

I've declared variables and their values before but I've never done this on a single line before.

If I write

```
A, B = 0.0, 2;
```

Does this mean

```
A = 0
```

and

```
B = 2?
```

Comment: Did you try to do it ?

Comment: It would in Python, but not in C.

Comment: that's not a *variable declaration in **C***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression

```
A, B = 0.0, 2;
```

is an expression with the comma operator (here are two comma operators). It can be presented like

```
( A ), ( B = 0.0 ), ( 2 );
```

As result the variable `B` will get the value 0.0. The variable `A` will be unchanged.

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
>   has its type and value

So the value of the above expression is `2` and the type is `int`.  The value of the expression is not used. So the only its side effect is assigning the value `0.0` to the variable `B`.

Comment: Wouldn't B be 2? I believe that the result of a sequence separated by the comma operator is the _last_ element evaluated. Hence the value assigned will be 2. That is also what your quote says: "_the result has its type and value_".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It would, if the , operator had higher precedence than =

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The assignment operator has higher priority than the comma operator.

Comment: Thanks. Never too old to learn.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I agree with you.:)